# Have lost the privilege to chat

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, privileges

Earlier I had 20 reputation points so I was able to chat to discuss my queries on Stack Overflow.

Then somebody down voted my question and I lost 2 reputation points and lost the ability to chat.

Now I again have 20 reputation points. How can I continue my discussion? Any lead is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Nothing you need to do but wait. It will take a while for the chat to pick that up again.

Comment: You were kicked out of the chat room in the middle of discussion?

Comment: Perhaps some privileges should survive rep loss?

Answer (score 6):

Chat profiles update (from memory) hourly when you are visiting the site; the "borderline rep" scenario is such as edge-case that it works fine for 99.(a lot of nines)% case. We *do* have a button to force an update for a user on-demand, but this is overkill most of the time - in particular, I notice that your chat profile has already updated now.

Comment: So the short answer is "wait an hour"?